# (Setting up SSL) invalid number of arguments in "ssl_certificate" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, certificate

I am trying to setup SSL on my server. I purchased my SSL certificate from Comodo.

I am following the tutorial they have made here: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1091/0/certificate-installation--nginx

On step 5, it tells me to run the following command: `sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

When I do so, this is the message output:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "ssl_certificate" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:45
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

So, I go to line 45:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_com/ssl-bundle.crt
```

In the Prerequisites section on step number two, it tells me to combine my domain.crt + the ca-bundle which I have done so.

I am clueless as to what I should do next.

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon at the end of the that line?

Comment: I'm missing a semicolon at 2 lines. Errors like these amaze me. Something so small can make it go wrong. If you post that as an answer ill pick you.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and hope it could be helpful:

I checked config and figured out that I just missed semicolon.
In your case:

> ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_com/ssl-bundle.crt;